# is it possible create a mesure in SSAS that calculates the total of rows in the fact table based on the value of field in the same fact table?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

i have created a cube in SSAS using visual studio, i have records in the fact table like this :

```
activity 1 : id_session = 1 , is_session_rebound = 1 , session_duration = 500
activity 2 : id_session = 2 , is_session_rebound = 0, session_duration = 600
activity 3 :  id_session = 2 , is_session_rebound = 0 , session_duration = 600
activity 4 :  id_session = 2 , is_session_rebound = 0 , session_duration = 600
```

i want to create a mesure tha give the total of distinct id_session having is_session_rebound = 1

i tried this

`COUNT( DISTINCT( FILTER( [fact_table].[id_session].Members, [fact_table].[is_session_rebound].CurrentMember = 1 ) ) )`